# Deconstructing slot machine reels?

Tags: reverse-engineering, genetic-algorithm, gambling

I have a movie of slot machine game play. How to extract only movie frames when the reels are stopped? During spinning game shows fake symbols, which are not part of the game mathematics. Until now I am doing it manually (by screen shots), which takes too much time and it will be nice to be automated.

I know how to do [image processing](http://raw.githubusercontent.com/TodorBalabanov/Slot-Machine-Symbols-Capture/master/src/Main.java) of single images and I get segments of symbols for each reel. Can you suggest me an algorithm with which to connect different segments and to deconstruct original strips? It is like a puzzle solving, but without clear information for the number of pieces and how exactly they match.